# Проблема с наследованием InMemoryDbService

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2

Делаю [пример](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6) из официального мануала Angular и столкнулся с проблемой наследования класса `InMemoryDbService`, в результате получаю вот такую ошибку:

> Property 'createDb' in type 'InMemoryDataService' is not assignable to
> the same property in base type 'InMemoryDbService'

Собственно, сделал только вот это:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { InMemoryDbService} from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InMemoryDataService extends InMemoryDbService {

  createDb(reqInfo?: RequestInfo): {} | Observable<{}> | Promise<{}> {
      //...
  }
}
```

базовый библиотечный класс объявлен вот так:

```
export declare abstract class InMemoryDbService {
    /**
    * ...
    */
    abstract createDb(reqInfo?: RequestInfo): {} | Observable<{}> | Promise<{}>;
}
```

Насколько хватает зрения и сообразительности, сигнатура единственного метода вроде бы совпадает.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {  }. Вы создаёте дочерний класс, а не имплементируетесь от существующего

Comment: @KonstantinFedorov ошибка осталась прежняя

Answer (score 2, accepted):

О важности разговора с котом :)

Пока писал вопрос возникла гипотеза, что ошибка могла возникнуть из-за конфликта имен для типа `RequestInfo`. И точно, если явно указать этот класс в импорте, то ошибка исчезает:

```
import { InMemoryDbService, RequestInfo } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
```

Другой тип `RequestInfo` в моей системе объявлен в файле `lib.dom.d.ts`.

Comment: в lib.dom.d.ts объявлены стандартные типы из браузера, очевидно ангуляр хочет использовать свой

Comment: @Grundy да, поэтому был конфликт имен. Мне нужен был `RequestInfo` объявленный в  `angular-in-memory-web-api`

Comment: Точнее тот, который объявлен в `interfaces.ts`, в самом `angular-in-memory-web-api` находятся только импорты необходимых типов